# How can the back button in action bar act as the back button on device?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, sharedpreferences, back-button

In Android if I start new Activity B from within activity A, Android will automatically save all the state of Activity A. So when I click back button on the device in Activity B, A will be restored to the state when I had started Activity B (for example: Spinners, ListView and Toggle Buttons all are in their previous positions).

BUT when I click the back button in action bar activity A starts fresh with no stored state. 
Is there any way to make this back button similar to the device's back or I have to use SharedPreferences and store every thing myself?

(api 8 and above for my app)

In one of the fragments in my app I have a ListView which is one of the fragments that needs to be in the same state when coming back from the next page. I have added the code below.
If any other part is needed please tell me and I will add the code.

The main activity code:
private ProgressDialog progress;

```
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(Farsi.Convert(getString(R.string.app_name_farsi)));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

Here is the code to my List Fragment:

```
public class SearchResultListFragment extends Fragment{
    Pagination pagination;
    boolean loadingMore = false;
    ListView list;
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    TextView text4;
    TextView text5;
    Button Btngetdata;
    private static String url = "https://www.....com/api/property/search";
    private static int currentFirstVisibleItem;
    public SearchResultArrayListAdaptor adapter ;
    LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONParse fetchclass = null;

    public SearchResultListFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
        ArrayAdapter<PropertyObject> aa =(ArrayAdapter<PropertyObject>) list.getAdapter();
        if (aa!= null){
            aa.clear();
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        list.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) getActivity());

        adapter = new SearchResultArrayListAdaptor(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_items, new ArrayList<PropertyObject>());
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        pagination = new Pagination(0,15);
        fetchclass = new JSONParse(getActivity());
        fetchclass.execute(url);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result_list, container, false);
        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewSearchResult);
        list.setOnScrollListener(
            new OnScrollListener(){
                private int currentVisibleItemCount;
                private int currentTotalItemCount;
                private int currentScrollState;
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                    this.isScrollCompleted();
                }
                private void isScrollCompleted() {
                    if (currentFirstVisibleItem + currentVisibleItemCount >= currentTotalItemCount) {
                        if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                            if(fetchclass!=null) {
                                pagination = new Pagination(this.currentTotalItemCount,15);
                                if(!(fetchclass.getStatus()== AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
                                    fetchclass= new JSONParse(getActivity());
                                    fetchclass.execute(url);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                fetchclass = new JSONParse(getActivity());
                                fetchclass.execute(url);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                    this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                    this.currentTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
                }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    //*********************************** inner class
    public class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        Context mContext;
        int checkBoxRooms;
        public JSONParse(Context context){
            mContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            PropertyFilter searchFilter = SearchFilterManager.initializePropertyFilter(new PropertyFilter(), getArguments());
            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            JSONParserForSearch jParser = new JSONParserForSearch();
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url, searchFilter, pagination);
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            // SHOW THE SPINNER WHILE LOADING FEEDS
            getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            PropertyObject propertyObject;
            try {
                jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("PropertyListings");
                if (jsonArray == null || jsonArray.length()<1){

//                  list.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtNoResult));
                }
                else {
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        propertyObject = new Gson().fromJson(c.toString(), new PropertyObject().getClass());
                        adapter.add(propertyObject);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
                // CHANGE THE LOADINGMORE STATUS TO PERMIT FETCHING MORE DATA
                loadingMore = false;

                // HIDE THE SPINNER AFTER LOADING FEEDS
                linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My layout XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewSearchResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    >
```

My Adapter is ArrayAdapter.
I have implemented isEmpty and getCount too.

My Activity For List:

```
public class SearchResultListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
static PropertyObject selectedPropertyObject;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("intentionOfOwner", intent.getIntExtra("intentionOfOwner",0));

    SearchResultListFragment fragobj=new SearchResultListFragment();
    fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    ///back button

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_result_list);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragobj).commit();
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View textView, int rowNumber, long arg3) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PropertyDetailActivity.class);
    PropertyObject po = (PropertyObject) arg0.getAdapter().getItem((int)arg3);
    intent.putExtra("listingID",po.getID());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

EDIT:
All right. I changed my API level from 8 to 11 to. 
Also I added getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); to onCreate() of activity.
And changes the onOptionsItemSelected as follows.

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent=new Intent(PropertyDetailActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.up:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.homeAsUp:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

BUT none of the switch cases gets the chance to run when I click the back button in the action bar!

Comment: There's a full explanation on how to do that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: Thank u for the useful link. I will read it carefully. But look at this auto generated comment in onOptionsItemSelected() method:   // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml. according to this (I have the parents in my manifest) shouldn't the back in action bar be handled automatically?

Comment: I will read it and apply everything needed and will inform you of the result. Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: In Activity B, you can call `OnBackPressed` in `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: OnBackPressed() no help.

Comment: @ CarlosJimenez : Accordind to the source u gave, the problem is caused by my project supporting API 8+ . Because of the usage of support library. As it seems I'm gonna have to go for Sherlok action bar rather than Google SupportLibrary :(

Comment: @CarlosJimenez: I updated my question. plz check. I read the guide and acted accordingly but still no success. What u suggesst?

Comment: Hey @Tina replace `R.id.home` with `android.R.id.home` on your switch statement